# Run GUI programs through SSH without window manager on host

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, gui

So, I have a Raspberry Pi running Arch Linux ARM.

I don't have a window manager on it as it's not exactly powerful, however I was wondering if it would be possible to SSH to it from another computer and use a GUI program but have it display on the computer I'm using to connect to it.

Or is this not possible without having a X server running on the Pi?

Comment: probably belongs on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's on-topic here, if it were specific to the RPi (or could provably be a problem with their distro) then I'd consider migrating but this is a generic Linux tools question.  Ignore the Raspberry Pi bit and read "headless linux box" instead if you like...

Comment: You don't need X-server on the Pi. What you do need, though, is an X-server on the host window is displayed on (so you might want to edit your question to include what is the computer you're using SSH from).

Comment: It is possible and a common use case. It’s called “X11 Forwarding”. Some distributions may pull in the X server as a dependency, but it doesn’t have be running.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, host computer is running Debian with Openbox, so would running `ssh -XY name@192.168.1.31` work? And would I then need to run `export DISPLAY=:0` or not?